# Unity: removing LODs through editor script

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to be able to remove all lods from lod group component as well as it's corresponding gameobjects from hierarchy through editor scripting.. Can y'all help me with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Are you sure you are using that language?

Answer (score 0):

The lod group class provides a method to get an array of all the lods [GetLods()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LODGroup.GetLODs.html).
Each lod class has a [list of renderers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LOD-renderers.html) relative to the gameobject assigned to that specific lod, each renderer object has a reference to the gameobject parent therefore is just a matter of calling the Destroy method for each gameobject. To delete the lods from the lod group just call SetLODs with an empty array as argument.

Answer (score 0):

A little late because I had to face a similar situation recently.
Here's the script I wrote to resolve the issue.

https://github.com/saadasghar96/Unity/blob/master/Utility/MultiComponentCopierCleaner.cs

Go under Earth People Studio > Multi-Component Cleaner

If you leave the 'component' field empty in the Multi-Component Cleaner, it will remove every type of component.
Type in "LOD" and the script will do the rest.

Be sure to back up the object you're cleaning in case things go wrong.